# jQuery .clone's argument meaning

Tags: jquery

I'm having some problem figuring out .`clone()`'s behavior. From what I understand from the documentation, data- attributes shouldn't be copied at all if I pass 'false' as its first argument, though, the fiddle below tells me the argument is not taken into account, (or that it doesn't concern data- attributes.)

```
withDataAndEvents (default: false)
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value is false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c37e1tck/

Any help would be welcome!

Edit: Thank you all for your answers.
Both answers helped me so I flagged the first. I wanted to give a point to each of you but apparently I need reputation that I don't have yet, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: The attributes are copied, but explicit data(handlers,`.data()`) isn't. http://jsfiddle.net/c37e1tck/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements.

Setting to `true` copies data set with [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) and event handlers such as [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) / [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to the new element.

[`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) will be copied either way. (Just like `class` or any other attribute in the HTML.) However, if changed with [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/), they will be reverted to their original values found in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What it means the don't copy the jQuery data, which is different from the `data-*` attributes. jQuery data api uses the data-* attribute values to initialize its internal data values, but is different from the html5 dataset.

```js
var $mydiv = $('#myDiv');

//this won't be copied as it is stored in the internal structure only
$mydiv.data('new', 'newvalue')

//the updated value won't be copied as that also is present in the internal structure but the initial data-* value will be present in the structure
$mydiv.find('span').data('another', 'new - value');

var $mydiv2 = $('#myDiv').clone(false).attr('id', 'myDiv2');

$('#container').append($mydiv2)
$('#myDiv2')
  .html($mydiv2.data('test') + ' ' + $mydiv2.find('span').data('another') + ' ' + $mydiv2.data('new'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="myDiv" data-test="Bar"><span data-another="Meh">Foo.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```